# What do I have to do when using libraries with BSD license?

Tags: java, bsd-license

I am making a game using [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) and this is their [license](http://lwjgl.org/license.php). What I don't understand is what must I do?

I plan on making a game and distributing it, not the source code just the .jar file and maybe sell it for a few dollars.

It said that I must retain the copyright, so would that mean I must include the doc folder that the library comes with in the jar or do I have to make something in-game like credits and say "made with LWJGL"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirements are really quite simple: Somewhere in your game or the documentation that you distribute along with it, you must mention that you use the Lwjgl library and reproduce its license text.

If your game can already display credits, then that is also where you should mention Lwjgl and its license.
Otherwise, if you have a file describing your game and which Jar files are needed (like a README file), then that is also a good place to mention Lwgjl and its license. If you don't have such a file, consider creating one.

Comment: Thanks, am going with the credits since am going to make it a runnable jar file so i would have any other files other than the game itself and i'll leave the readme file with their license

Comment: quick question, would it also be okay if i just left the doc folder that the lwjgl comes with right next to the jars as well? they seem to have all the licenses

Comment: @androidmaster: To fulfil the license requirements of lwjgl it would be ok, but that *doc* folder, and the license files in it, can easily be misunderstood to apply to your game as well.

Comment: Applied to my game? I dont think so since i left it in the folder where only lwjgl is located, seperated from my game. I created a lib folder for only that stuff. So i would think that i leave the doc folder